# To find EXE window is active or not

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-2.0

I have a different requirement in one of my projects, when I run my exe and make it idle
(i.e. without click, min, max), after a period of time (timer) it should be automatically closed. If anyone clicked before the particular time, the timer must reset for the same period.
How can I find out whether the exe is idle or not?

Comment: I've just changed your edit where you added "winforms" to the body of the question to add it as a tag instead. It's more usefully placed there and will help others find this question and the answers to it =)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [`Application.Idle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.idle.aspx) event (Note: Only applicable to a WinForms application, as far as I'm aware).

If you combine it with a timer that you stop/reset whenever your application receives input, that should give you pretty much what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi rob thanks for your reply,actually i used some unmanaged code and achieved it.i will post it here.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

public class GlobalMouseHandler : IMessageFilter

```
{

    public delegate void EventHandlerForActiveState();

    public event EventHandlerForActiveState onActive;

    public event EventHandlerForActiveState onStateChanged;

    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;

    //private const int WM_HSCROLL = 0x114;

    //private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;        

    private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;

    private const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202;

    private const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x204;

    private const int WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x205;

    //private const int WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x209;

    private const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x20A;

    private const int WM_GETMINMAXINFO = 0x024;

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)

    {

        if (m.Msg == 275)

        {

            return false;

        }

        switch (m.Msg)

        {

            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:

                if (onActive != null)

                    onActive();

                break;

            case WM_LBUTTONUP:

                if (onActive != null)

                    onActive();

                break;

            case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:

                if (onActive != null)

                    onActive();

                break;

            case WM_RBUTTONUP:

                if (onActive != null)

                    onActive();

                break;

            case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:

                if (onActive != null)

                    onActive();

                break;

            //case WM_ACTIVATE:

            //    if (onActive != null)

            //        onActive();

            //    break;

            case WM_KEYDOWN:

                if (onActive != null)

                    onActive();

                break;

            case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:

                if (onStateChanged != null)

                    onStateChanged();

                break;



            //case WM_HSCROLL:

            //    if (onActive != null)

            //        onActive();

            //    break;

            //case WM_VSCROLL:

            //    if (onActive != null)

            //        onActive();

            //    break;

        }

        return false;

    }

}
```

GlobalMouseHandler handle = new GlobalMouseHandler();
            handle.onActive += new GlobalMouseHandler.EventHandlerForActiveState(handle_onActive);
            Application.AddMessageFilter(handle);
I used this class and done this.

Comment: Missed some.  Check http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/815cfbf9-2303-4637-a7c2-d25ef5c1eeb3